# Facebook file doesn't exist showing up continuously in apache log

Tags: facebook, apache, facebook-like

I am seeing these error entries in our apache logs all the time.
We have the FB like button on our website

Any suggestions on what's causing it, or how to rectify?

> [Fri Oct 18 07:50:22 2013] [error] [client 108.168.210.164] File does not exist: /var/www/www.facebook.com
>
> [Fri Oct 18 07:50:49 2013] [error] [client 108.168.210.164] File does not exist: /var/www/www.facebook.com
>
> [Fri Oct 18 07:50:54 2013] [error] [client 5.10.84.4] File does not exist: /var/www/www.facebook.com

Comment: Probably a missing "http://" on the URLs.

Comment: Silly me...  that's it!

Answer (score 0):

More often than not, Apache errors of the form

> [Fri Oct 18 07:50:22 2013] [error] [client 108.168.210.164] File does not exist: /var/www/www.hostname.com

indicate that the client has received a relative URL, ie one without "http://".